# Can I create twice nodes within in one Source code?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all，
As a ROS newbie I am studying the service and write some testcode based on tutorials. it works well but one addition question raised. sorry if it is a silly question...
For exp，if ROBOT had completed one task (nodeA) it needs notify other node(B) some parameters (position，tate etc..) as this is not a frequent messge would be better use service rather than topic.
Then Node B need do something else based on these message.

My question is as each source code can only create one node(is that correct understanding??) so within the node A，can I create another service node (service client C) that to communicate with server node B? If it is not allowed，what is the suggest solution?

Thanks at much
Mac

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323147/can-i-create-twice-nodes-within-in-one-source-code?/) by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My question is as each source code can only create one node(is that correct understanding??)

each *program* (or process) can only start a single node in ROS 1.

> so within the node A，can I create another service node (service client C) that to communicate with server node B?

No, you cannot create a second *node* in the same process.

> If it is not allowed，what is the suggest solution?

You can create any number of service clients and servers per node.

The only limitation is on the node, not the service client/server, publishers/subscribers or action clients/servers.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on 2019-05-14**:
Thank for the quick answer.
OK so I maybe confuse the node  and a service?
If Node A is a control node (charge of the Robot movement control，i.e. publisher to cmd_vel )， it can not create a server client node C ，is that right?
But I can write code to create Node C (service client) and node B (service server)， and in node A I can use (Don't know the proper name) the Node C to communicate with Node B?
Please let me know if that is correct understanding..

**Comment by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on 2019-05-14**:
BTW，for above node B(a server client) it usually be used and shutdown. If I still need that does that mean NodeB creator shall not exit but keep alive? That looks violate the concept of service?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-15**:
I'm not sure I completely follow your follow-up question. It also seems very similar to your questions(s) in #q323056.

**Comment by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on 2019-05-15**:
Thanks I finally manage it out..